# Accessing last x characters of a string in Bash

Tags: string, bash, extract

I found out that with `${string:0:3}` one can access the first 3 characters of a string. Is there a equivalently easy method to access the last three characters?

Answer (score 375, accepted):

Last three characters of `string`:

```
${string: -3}
```

or

```
${string:(-3)}
```

(mind the space between `:` and `-3` in the first form).

Please refer to the [Shell Parameter Expansion in the reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
${parameter:offset}
${parameter:offset:length}

Expands to up to length characters of parameter starting at the character
specified by offset. If length is omitted, expands to the substring of parameter
starting at the character specified by offset. length and offset are arithmetic
expressions (see Shell Arithmetic). This is referred to as Substring Expansion.

If offset evaluates to a number less than zero, the value is used as an offset
from the end of the value of parameter. If length evaluates to a number less than
zero, and parameter is not ‘@’ and not an indexed or associative array, it is
interpreted as an offset from the end of the value of parameter rather than a
number of characters, and the expansion is the characters between the two
offsets. If parameter is ‘@’, the result is length positional parameters
beginning at offset. If parameter is an indexed array name subscripted by ‘@’ or
‘*’, the result is the length members of the array beginning with
${parameter[offset]}. A negative offset is taken relative to one greater than the
maximum index of the specified array. Substring expansion applied to an
associative array produces undefined results.

Note that a negative offset must be separated from the colon by at least one
space to avoid being confused with the ‘:-’ expansion. Substring indexing is
zero-based unless the positional parameters are used, in which case the indexing
starts at 1 by default. If offset is 0, and the positional parameters are used,
$@ is prefixed to the list.
```

---

Since this answer gets a few regular views, let me add a possibility to address [John Rix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/597034)'s comment; as he mentions, if your string has length less than 3, `${string: -3}` expands to the empty string. If, in this case, you want the expansion of `string`, you may use:

```
${string:${#string}<3?0:-3}
```

This uses the `?:` ternary if operator, that may be used in [Shell Arithmetic](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic); since as documented, the offset is an arithmetic expression, this is valid.

---

### Update for a POSIX-compliant solution

The previous part gives the best option *when using Bash.* If you want to target POSIX shells, here's an option (that doesn't use pipes or external tools like `cut`):

```
# New variable with 3 last characters removed
prefix=${string%???}
# The new string is obtained by removing the prefix a from string
newstring=${string#"$prefix"}
```

One of the main things to observe here is the use of quoting for `prefix` *inside* the parameter expansion. This is mentioned in the [POSIX ref](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) (at the end of the section):

> The following four varieties of parameter expansion provide for substring processing. In each case, pattern matching notation (see Pattern Matching Notation), rather than regular expression notation, shall be used to evaluate the patterns. If parameter is '#', '*', or '@', the result of the expansion is unspecified. If parameter is unset and set -u is in effect, the expansion shall fail. Enclosing the full parameter expansion string in double-quotes shall not cause the following four varieties of pattern characters to be quoted, **whereas quoting characters within the braces shall have this effect.** In each variety, if word is omitted, the empty pattern shall be used.

This is important if your string contains special characters. E.g. (in dash),

```
$ string="hello*ext"
$ prefix=${string%???}
$ # Without quotes (WRONG)
$ echo "${string#$prefix}"
*ext
$ # With quotes (CORRECT)
$ echo "${string#"$prefix"}"
ext
```

Of course, this is usable only when then number of characters is known in advance, as you have to hardcode the number of `?` in the parameter expansion; but when it's the case, it's a good portable solution.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work if your string is shorter than the negative offset you supply. You just get an empty string in such instances.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf   How can use this along with command substitution ? I'm trying to extract the last three characters of my hostname  `deppfx@localhost:/tmp$ echo ${$(hostname): -3}`    `-bash: ${$(hostname): -3}: bad substitution`

Comment: @deppfx: you can't in Bash. Use a temporary variable: `temp=$(hostname); echo "${temp: -3}"`. Bash also has the `HOSTNAME` variable (that may or may not differ from the output of `hostname`). If you want to use it, just do `echo "${HOSTNAME: -3}"`.

Comment: How can you use this from the output of a pipe? For instance, `some func | echo ${string: -3}` -- how do I assign the output of `some func` to `string`?

Comment: @MichaelHays: Just assign the output of your function: `string=$(some func)` and then `echo "${string: -3}"`.

Comment: Intuitively, I had tried `${var:-n}` (but missed the space). So it hadn't worked.

Comment: How do I mix the two up? `echo ${"${filename#pcre-}"%???????}` doesn’t work.

Comment: @КонстантинВан You can't do parameter expansion within parameter expansion (you can't nest them!). You have to use a temporary variable for that.

Answer (score 66):

You can use `tail`:

```
$ foo="1234567890"
$ echo -n $foo | tail -c 3
890
```

A somewhat roundabout way to get the last three characters would be to say:

```
echo $foo | rev | cut -c1-3 | rev
```

Comment: The "tail" also useful in dash, when bash unavailable. E.g. upstart script section.

Comment: I also found `tail` useful however it is not useful when you wanted to print last 3 char at every line.  I mean if you pipe the string from a file by `cat`

Answer (score 19):

**1. Generalized Substring**

To generalise the question and the answer of gniourf_gniourf (as this is what I was searching for), if you want to cut a **range** of characters from, say, 7th from the end to 3rd from the end, you can use this syntax:

```
${string: -7:4}
```

Where 4 is the length of course (7-3).

**2. Alternative using `cut`**

In addition, while the solution of gniourf_gniourf is obviously the best, I just wanted to add an alternative solution using `cut`:

```
echo $string | cut -c $((${#string}-2))-
```

Here, `${#string}` is the length of the string, and the trailing "-" means cut to the end.

**3. Alternative using `awk`**

This solution instead uses the substring function of `awk` to select a substring which has the syntax `substr(string, start, length)` going to the end if the length is omitted.  `length($string)-2)` thus picks up the last three characters.

```
echo $string | awk '{print substr($1,length($1)-2) }'
```

Comment: a variant not mentioned in the other answer is to combine this `cut` approach of calculating the start/stop first and then just using these variables in the parameter expansion (also worth mentioning that `cut` and bash offsets start at 1 and zero, respectively, so this would need to be figured into the calculations, which I'm not doing here): `start=$((${#string}-3)); stop=$((${#string}));` and then `echo ${string: $start : $stop}` vs `echo $string | cut -c "$start"-"$stop"`

Comment: (oh, never mind -- I see that my comment doesn't address the problem of the string being too short, and then causing no output at all -- both the cut and string param expansion. Still, breaking it out into variables (without necessarily calling out to extra commands) makes it easier to read & would still be a good idea, I think.)

Answer (score 18):

Another workaround is to use `grep -o` with a little regex magic to get three chars followed by the end of line:

```
$ foo=1234567890
$ echo $foo | grep -o ...$
890
```

To make it optionally get the 1 to 3 last chars, in case of strings with less than 3 chars, you can use `egrep` with this regex:

```
$ echo a | egrep -o '.{1,3}$'
a
$ echo ab | egrep -o '.{1,3}$'
ab
$ echo abc | egrep -o '.{1,3}$'
abc
$ echo abcd | egrep -o '.{1,3}$'
bcd
```

You can also use different ranges, such as `5,10` to get the last five to ten characters.

Answer (score 0):

Guess the easiest way is:

```
$ str=123456789
$ echo ${str:(-3)}
789
```

Or you could do some math:

```
$ cnt=$((${#str}-3))
$ echo $cnt
6
$ echo ${str:cnt:3}
789
```

Here ^ `${#str}` will give you the number of symbols in string and then it decreased by 3, so the final `echo` is like print 3 symbols starting from 6.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the maximum last N characters of a string **OR** the **entire string**, if the string **length does not exceed maximum N** characters, then you can use:

```
str=1234567890

echo $(N=8 && [ ${#str} -gt ${N} ] && echo ${str:0-${N}} || echo ${str})
34567890

echo $(N=20 && [ ${#str} -gt ${N} ] && echo ${str:0-${N}} || echo ${str})
1234567890
```

Answer (score -1):

a very nice option is to use double colon to extract the string except the nth character like:

echo ${string::-3}

Comment: Isn’t that the opposite of what the question is about?