# Why can't I extract the last three characters of my hostname using the below shell parameter expansion?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

`deppfx@localhost:/tmp$ echo ${$(hostname): -3}`

`-bash: ${$(hostname): -3}: bad substitution`

I am looking for the output as `ost`.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19858692/598175

Answer (score 2):

It should be `${variable: -3}`. Don't try to substitute command.

Answer (score 1):

The substitution works in variables, not in commands.

```
echo $(myVar=$(hostname);echo ${myVar: -3})
```